# Chapterbib with subdirectories does not compile

Tags: bibtex

I'm using chapterbib package to generate a bibliography for each chapter. But the compilation fails.

Here is the content of my principal.tex file:

```
\documentclass[phd]{theseUL}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{topcapt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotfloat}

\usepackage[square,sort,comma, authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

\begin{document}

\part{Contexte général et état de l'art}
\include{../chap1_introduction/chap1_introduction}
\input{../chap2_definitions/chap2_definitions}

\end{document}
```

Here is the content of chap1_introduction.tex

```
\chapter{Introduction}  %%This is chapter 1

\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

Text

\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{principal}
```

And so for the content of chap2_definitions.tex

```
\chapter{Definition} %%This is chapter 2

\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Definition}

Text

\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{principal}
```

This is how I compile my documents:

1. pdflatex principal.tex (success)
2. pdflatex principal.tex (success)
3. bibtex principal (2 errors, I guess it is normal: see output #1)
4. bibtex ../chap1_introduction/chap1_introduction (see output #2)
5. bibtex ../chap2_definitions/chap2_definitions (see output #3)
6. pdflatex principal.tex
7. pdflatex principal.tex

Output #1

```
XXXX@IFTEaigny2:~/Phd/principal$ bibtex principal
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: principal.aux
The style file: authordate1.bst
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 51 of file principal.aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {authordate1}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Illegal, another \bibdata command---line 52 of file principal.aux
 : \bibdata
 :         {principal}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: principal.bib
Warning--to sort, need author or key in GrownUpDigital2009
Warning--empty author in GrownUpDigital2009
Warning--empty journal in GrownUpDigital2009
Warning--empty journal in Torres2008
(There were 2 error messages)
```

Output #2

```
XXXX@IFTEaigny2:~/Phd/principal$ bibtex principal
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99c (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: ../chap1_introduction/chap1_introduction.aux
The style file: authordate1.bst
I couldn't open database file chap1_introduction.bib
---line 43 of file ../chap1_introduction/chap1_introduction.aux
 : \bibdata{chap1_introduction
 :                            }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file ../chap1_introduction/chap1_introduction.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Downes2005"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Hadjerrouit2005"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Hadjerrouit2007"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Wilson2007"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Seffah2002"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Torres2008"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Downes2004"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "GrownUpDigital2009"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

output #3 is same than output #2

principal.bib is the entire citation databse for the whole document and is in /principal; so I have principal/principal.bib.

Should I compile the chapters bibtex from the chapter subdirectory, or from the principal subdirectory as I did? I tried both withe the same result.

Thank you.

Comment: Crosspost to [LaTeX-community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=84967#p84967).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already answered [here on LaTeX-Community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=25023), but also here my answer. I can see that you use `\input` for including the chapters in this line:

```
\input{../chap2_definitions/chap2_definitions}
```

However, you should use `\include` instead, this way you would get .aux files for each chapter which can be processed. Otherwise, with `\input`, you would need `\cbinput` or the `cbunit` environment. However, `\include` is strongly recommended. You use chapters, for sure starting a new page, so `\include` would be fine.

Here's also a solution: [chapterbib | References following each Chapter](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=3410). Also there, the solution was using `\include` but additionally having the files in the same directory.

Comment: Hallo Stefan,

I did already tried both \include and \input but could not make the compilation works. I did already also saw the page you are referring to me. I took the time to look after Chapterbib reference on http://latex-community.org/ and else where. Today is my third day of search on the topic.

I believe the compilation errors comes from the structure in subdirectories of my project.

Comment: As I said earlier, this is how I compiled my documents:
**Questions:**


 1. pdflatex principal.tex (success)
 2. pdflatex principal.tex (success)
 3. bibtex principal (2 errors, I guess it is normal: see output #1)
 4. bibtex ../chap1_introduction/chap1_introduction (see output #2)
 5. bibtex ../chap2_definitions/chap2_definitions (see output #3)
 6. pdflatex principal.tex
 7. pdflatex principal.tex

1-When I run this command line **bibtex ../chap1_introduction/chap1_introduction** I run it from the principal directory. Is that correct?

Comment: 2-Also as the content of my chapter files showed it, those files has no header and start directly with the chapter content; also there is no [code]\end{document}[/code] at the end of those files too, and I understand why. But it is not possible to compile such a file, for example the chap1_introduction itself to produce the chap1_introduction.aux file which is needed by the principal.tex compilation process.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed. I think errors came from the used document class package. Instead of `\documentclass[phd]{theseUL}` I used this class package `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}` and compilation run successfuly.
Thank you Stefan for your support.